# Getting error while trying to copy STL Set into Vector

Tags: c++, vector, set

I am trying to initialize vector by already preset Set but getting error

```
vector<string> findRepeatedDnaSequences(string s) {
    int size = s.length();
    set<string>container;
    unordered_map<string,int>hmap;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        string first=s.substr(i,10);
        if(hmap.find(first)!=hmap.end()){
            // if((i-hmap[first])>=10)
                container.insert(first);
        }else hmap[first] = i;
    }

    // ERROR IN THIS LINE 
    return vector<string>res(container.begin(), container.end());
}
```

```
anagrams.cpp:21:26: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction return vector<string>res((container.begin(), container.end()));
```

Comment: voting to close as a typo.  Remove the variable name from the return line, you don't need a named variable there.  `return vector<string>res(container.begin(), container.end());` should be `return vector<string>(container.begin(), container.end());`

Comment: `vector<string>res` is a variable declaration. You could do `vector<string>res(...); return res;` or do `return vector<string>(...);`.

Comment: yeah thanks, it worked.

Comment: You might even do `return {container.begin(), container.end()};`

Comment: @GemTaylor oh thanks man I just tried it and it worked just fine, So it automatically converts set into Vector? and it worked much faster before it took 56ms for code to execute now 44ms.

Comment: C++11 tries hard to make it so you don't need to keep writing complex type statements. This is basically just list initialisation, and the compiler already knows the return type. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Comment: okay thanks, helped.